# Multiple tasks scheduling caused deadlock

Tags: c#, multithreading

The application is for a telephone service. All of calls are put in a queue. Because of port limitations, each time the application can only take the maximum call up to 4.

In the following code, I set the maximum semaphore as 4 of course.

However in this small simulation program, it went to deadlock. None of task is finished.

```
class Program
{
    static readonly Queue<string> phoneNumbers = new Queue<string>();
    static Semaphore semaphore;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string[] dialCollection = new string[9];
        dialCollection[0] = "test 00000000000";
        dialCollection[1] = "test 11111111111";
        dialCollection[2] = "test 22222222222";
        dialCollection[3] = "test 33333333333";
        dialCollection[4] = "test 44444444444"; 
        dialCollection[5] = "test 55555555555";
        dialCollection[6] = "test 66666666666";
        dialCollection[7] = "test 77777777777";
        dialCollection[8] = "test 88888888888";
        foreach (var item in dialCollection)
        {
            phoneNumbers.Enqueue(item);
        }
        semaphore = new Semaphore(0, 4);
        Console.WriteLine("Begin");
        List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
        do
        {
            string phoneNumber = phoneNumbers.Dequeue();
            try
            {
                tasks.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { MakeCall(phoneNumber); }));
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                //put the number back in the queue if the MakeCall method throws an exception...
                phoneNumbers.Enqueue(phoneNumber);
            }
        }
        while (phoneNumbers.Count > 0);
        Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
        Console.WriteLine("End");  //code not reach this break point.
        Console.Read();
    }

    private static void MakeCall(string phoneNumber)
    {
        semaphore.WaitOne();
        Console.WriteLine(phoneNumber);
        semaphore.Release();
    }
}
```

Comment: A minor quibble given that this an admitted sample project, but what's to stop this from going into an infinite loop if you have a "bad" phone number that always throws an exception? It will keep getting re-added to the queue.

Comment: @SvenGrosen, honestly, I don't know. Do you have any thought?

Comment: I'd suggest not re-adding it to the queue, and instead display some sort of error message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Initial Count on the semaphore is set to 0, so none are available. You have two choices, construct it with all four available:

```
semaphore = new Semaphore(4, 4);
```

Or release the 4 before you start your `WaitAll`

```
semaphore.Release(4);
```

Answer (score 1):

You set the initial value of the semaphore to 0, which means at the start of your program zero items can return from `WaitOne` until `Release` is called.

You want your semaphore to be initialized to 4, not 0.